# Thymeleaf Sorting Set

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I print values of a `Set` as:

```
<td th:text="${#strings.listJoin(company.departments, ',')}"></td>
```

Result is something like:

```
Management,Marketing
```

However, value order is changed when I refresh the page due to it is not a sorted set. As like:

```
Marketing,Management
```

I want them to be ordered. So, I tried:

```
<td th:text="${#strings.listJoin(#lists.sort(company.departments), ',')}"></td>
```

However, result is numbers:

```
1,2
```

What I miss?

Comment: And you can't change the type to a collection that enables sorting?

Comment: Its weird that lists.sort returns something else. According to th source, it should work. https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/2.1-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/util/ListUtils.java#L106-L112

Can't you change Set  to SortedSet?

Comment: I want to solve it at Thymeleaf. It should work according to documentation.

Comment: I recommend you load TH sources, step debug into it and investigate.

Comment: this source is for version 2.1, if you are using other version, it might have a bug or it might be doing something else.